# Arch Linux Install, Why is arch-chroot giving me an error?

Tags: linux, installation, mount, arch-linux, chroot

I'm following the Arch Linux install instructions [found here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners%27_Guide) from a live cd, and I'm stuck issuing the following command:

```
# arch-chroot /mnt
mount: sys is already mounted or /mnt/sys busy
       sys is already mounted on /sys
       sys is already mounted on /mnt/sys
==> ERROR: failed to setup API filesystems in chroot /mnt
```

Can someone explain to me what sys is and how it got mounted? How do I proceed to install Arch from here? I tried to reload the live cd a number of times but I keep coming back to this.

Comment: Would you mind indicating what partitions did you create exactly how you mounted and in what order? also, try with the latest iso (2013.01.04)

Comment: /mnt should not be used unless it is not used for mounting other filesystems (which is is, usually). Make a new folder somewhere such as /newChroot or /mnt/fresh-install, mount a block device there (/dev/sda1 for example) and use that as the root folder.

Answer (score 2):

`/sys` is a virtual file system that interfaces with the kernel. It is meant to replace `/proc`. More at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysfs

By the sounds of it, you have `/mnt/sys` mounted, try `umount /mnt/sys` or better yet, reboot. If it is doing this after the reboot, then `arch-chroot` is probably has a typo, `mount /sys /mnt/sys` should be `mount --bind /mnt/sys`. I could potentially help more if you could post the output of `mount`. Not sure if you have figured the solution out, as you posted it nearly a month ago.